# JS - jQuery dynamically add and remove fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, duplicates, form-fields

I am trying to make a dynamically duplicated field with jQuery :

The HTML (PHP) code :

```
<div  id="widget_dup">
    <p>

    <textarea class="code" cols="50" rows="5" id="o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content]"  name="o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content]"  value="<?php //echo $o99_brsa_options['brsa_dash_wdgt_content']; ?>"/><?php 
                        echo $o99_brsa_options['brsa_dash_wdgt_content']; 
                        ?></textarea>
                        <label class="description" for="o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content]">
                        </br><?php _e('Content for 1st widget', 'o99-brsa-domain'); ?>
                        </label>

    </p>
</div>
<div id="addScnt">add</div><div id="remScnt">remove</div>
```

the JS was assembled from some snippets I found  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                //http://jsfiddle.net/obmero99/ZD9Ky/

                    // <![CDATA[

                    jQuery(function() {
                            var scntDiv = jQuery('#widget_dup');
                            var prevDiv = scntDiv.html();

                            var i = jQuery('#widget_dup p').size() + 1;

                            jQuery('#addScnt').live('click', function() {

                                    jQuery(prevDiv).appendTo(scntDiv);

                                    i++;
                                    //alert (prevDiv);
                                    return false;
                            });

                            jQuery('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                                    if( i > 2 ) {
                                            jQuery(this).parents('p').remove();
                                            i--;
                                    }
                                    return false;
                            });
                    });

                    // ]]>
                </script>
```

The problem is that  this code will duplicate the fields ok, but without changing the ID , names and other attributes ( `ID`, `NAME` ,`FOR` etc.. )

I have tried to do : `jQuery(this).attr('id')+i;` and `jQuery(this).attr('name')+i;`, but it does not work as I intend. infact, it does not work at all. :-)

How can I modify the `attr()` of the field while is theory it does not exists yet ?

As per comments: fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/uZuWA/

Comment: Instead of using .html(), use .clone(), and you can set attributes with .attr() as youve been trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct use of setting attribute is

```
$(this).attr('id', i);
```

You should know, that the better use is with `clone()`, as Ian suggested!

Demo with `.clone`

http://jsbin.com/oqalig/1/edit

Comment: You are not setting attribute here but getting instead

Comment: You are right, I edited it ... missed, a comma instead of "+"

Comment: but using CLONE makes the script works only ONCE . aand also, It does not seem to change the ID´s .. Is there anything else wrong there ?

Comment: ok, I understand it is working as a general rule, but on my script it does not. So I figure I have done something else wrong there..

Comment: This seems like another question. Can you recreate your problem code in jsbin / jsfiddle?

Comment: @drinchev  - thanks for following :-) I added a fiddle to the question. and it is the same essential question. why is it not working :-)

Comment: @drinchev  - I also changed the `live()` to `on()` in the fiddle. (deprecated)

Comment: Thanks .. It works great now, I think I can handle the other attricutes :-) Thanks a bunch.